# ggplot2 question: Having trouble adding Shapefile to ggplot2 using readOGR and st_read

Tags: r, ggplot2, qgis, r-sf

I have a question on how to add a shapefile of 3 polygons onto a ggplot. If anyone could help--that'd be great!

While I'm trying to generate an animation (illustrating GPS movement across time) using the package moveVis, I'm only having trouble with the ggplot2 sections.Tried both readOGR and st_read > geom_sf and they don't work.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could take a second look. Thank you and have a great day.

Shapefile [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/07e33c485594c1d868349afdadaf918120200510223456/8362c9):

```
#data

df <- structure(list(location.long = c(103.78857, 103.78835, 103.78845, 
103.78845, 103.78845, 103.78845, 103.78845, 103.78565, 103.78565, 
103.78482, 103.78504, 103.78548, 103.78546, 103.78546, 103.78897, 
103.78963, 103.78982, 103.78812, 103.78897, 103.7875), location.lat = c(1.40311, 
1.40329, 1.40374, 1.40374, 1.40374, 1.40374, 1.40374, 1.40347, 
1.40347, 1.40305, 1.40249, 1.40303, 1.40228, 1.40228, 1.4038, 
1.40381, 1.40364, 1.40377, 1.4038, 1.40351), timestamp = c("7/6/19 7:50", 
"7/6/19 8:20", "7/6/19 8:42", "7/6/19 8:50", "7/6/19 9:20", "7/6/19 9:45", 
"7/6/19 10:10", "7/6/19 16:10", "7/6/19 16:40", "7/6/19 17:10", 
"7/6/19 17:40", "7/6/19 18:10", "7/6/19 18:40", "7/6/19 19:10", 
"25/6/19 7:05", "25/6/19 7:35", "25/6/19 8:05", "25/6/19 8:20", 
"25/6/19 8:35", "25/6/19 9:05"), troop = c("Main", "Main", "Main", 
"Main", "Main", "Main", "Main", "Main", "Main", "Main", "Main", 
"Main", "Main", "Main", "Main", "Main", "Main", "Main", "Main", 
"Main"), survey_method = c("Scan", "Scan", "Ad_libitum", "Scan", 
"Scan", "Scan", "Ad_libitum", "Scan", "Scan", "Scan", "Scan", 
"Scan", "Scan", "Scan", "Scan", "Scan", "Scan", "Ad_libitum", 
"Scan", "Scan"), data_tag = c("NSF-M1a", "NSF-M1a", "NSF-M1a", 
"NSF-M1a", "NSF-M1a", "NSF-M1a", "NSF-M1a", "NSF-M1a/R1", "NSF-M1a/R1", 
"NSF-M1a/R1", "NSF-M1a/R1", "NSF-M1a/R1", "NSF-M1a/R1", "NSF-M1a/R1", 
"NSF-M1b", "NSF-M1b", "NSF-M1b", "NSF-M1b", "NSF-M1b", "NSF-M1b"
), troop2 = c("NSF", "NSF", "NSF", "NSF", "NSF", "NSF", "NSF", 
"NSF", "NSF", "NSF", "NSF", "NSF", "NSF", "NSF", "NSF", "NSF", 
"NSF", "NSF", "NSF", "NSF")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Script here:

```
#reorder timestamps in ascending order
df<-df[order(df$timestamp),]

#remove duplicates
df <- df[!duplicated(df$timestamp),]

#convert time to time class
df$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df$timestamp, format = '%d/%m/%y %H:%M', tz='Singapore')

m <- moveVis::df2move(df, x = "location.long", y="location.lat",            time="timestamp",
            proj ="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs",  
            track_id="troop2",
            removeDuplicatedTimestamps=T)

m <- moveVis::align_move(m, res = 180 , digit = 0, unit = "mins") 

#Modify axis if necessary
ext <- extent(m) * 6

frames2 = frames_spatial(m, trace_show=F, equidistant = F, map_service= "carto",
            map_type = "light") %>%
            add_labels(title= "Monitoring Survey", caption = "(2019-2020)", 
                x = "Longitude", y="Latitude") %>%
                add_timestamps(type = "label") %>%
                add_progress(colour="white") %>%
                add_northarrow(colour="white",position="bottomleft") %>%
                add_scalebar(colour="black",position="bottomright", distance=NULL, units = "km"
                )

length(frames2)
frames2[[50]]

#Load a layer with multiple polygons

#method 01: with readOGR

homerange_all <- readOGR(dsn=".", "homerange_all_v02", ) 
plot(homerange_all) #looks alright when plotted 

## 'fortify' the data to get a dataframe format required by ggplot2
homerange_all_f <-broom::tidy(homerange_all) 
#unfortunately, df loses the id col, which was what I wanted to visualise in different colours in 

#Getting warnings too--what does this mean? 
#Regions defined for each Polygons
#Warning messages:
#1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
#2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
#  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
#3: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
#  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
#4: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
#  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector

frames3 = add_gg(frames2, gg = expr(geom_polygon(data = homerange_all_f, aes(x = "long", y = "lat", group="id"), 
                                            colour = "id", linetype = "solid")) , data = homerange_all_f) 

frames3[[100]]

#Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
#method2: use st_read

homerange_02     <- st_read("homerange_all_v02.shp")
homerange_02$id<- as.factor(homerange_02$id)
frames4 = add_gg(frames2, gg = expr(geom_sf(data = homerange_02, aes(group = "id"),show.legend="id" ,
                                            colour =  "black")) , data = homerange_02) 
#eror: 
#Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
#Not sure how to fix this either

frames4[[100]]
#nothing shows up on the map, except for the axis, title and legend.
```

Comment: Could you simplify this to the smallest example possible? You may be more likely to get assistance.

Comment: ah it's the min. no. of steps--since it involves another package outside of ggplot2 that uses the ggplot2 environment. not sure if the issue is because of the package vs ggplot2. :/  how would you suggest I simplify it even further?

Comment: I have some gps data to look at myself next week, I will try out the moveVis package and see if I learn anything helpful.

Comment: Thank you and all the best Mark! :)

Comment: Here's some suggestions: 1) start from a fresh R session and use `library()` statements to show which packages are required. 2) show that a simple `ggplot()` of your data and shapefile works with `geom_sf()` - note you will need to convert df to an sf object. 3) confirm with `st_crs() that both objects have the same projection. 4) I'm running R4, for which readOGR is not available. Are all your packages up to date?

Comment: 5) is there a better place to share your shapefiles from? wetransfer says they will be unavailable in a week.

Comment: Ha! I am now up to a similar point - trying to add an existing shapefile or sf object to the frames - no success so far.

Comment: Does `frames2` render properly? I now have an example working similar to yours with that adds polygons from a shapefile (turned into sf object) like your `homerange02` using code like this: `frames4 = add_gg(frames, gg = expr(geom_sf(data=my_sf_object_from_shapefile, colour = "blue", lty = "dotted", fill = NA)))` Even though I get the warning about projections (even though CRS is the same) the result works. I should write a blog post on this experience - it was more difficult than I expected getting it all set up.